# Printing gitignores

Tags: java, design-patterns, error-handling

I have written a simple program in Java 7 to write the `.gitignore` of different file types:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Oye {
    private static final String HELP_TXT = "help.txt";
    private static final String DATA = "gitignore";
    private HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Oye() {
    // Eager approach, building the map in the constructor. Is it good?
        File file = new File(DATA);
        if (file.exists()) {
          if (file.isDirectory()) {
              findFiles(file.listFiles());
          }
      } else {
        println("No data folder: " + DATA);
      }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
      printFile(HELP_TXT);
      return;
    }

    Oye oye = new Oye();
    if (args[0].equals("ls")) {
        oye.listFiles();
    } else {
        printFile(oye.getFilePath(args[0]));
    }
}

public void findFiles(File[] files) {
    for (File file: files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            findFiles(file.listFiles());
        } else {
            String fileName = file.getName();
            if (fileName.endsWith(".gitignore")) {
                fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf(".gitignore"));
                map.put(fileName, file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}

private String getFilePath(String name) {
    if (map.containsKey(name)) {
      return map.get(name);
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such file: " + name);
    }
}

private static void printFile(String path) {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File(path));
        String line;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
    }
}

private static void println(String txt) {
  System.out.println(txt);
}

private void listFiles() {
    for (String key: map.keySet()) {
        println(key);
    }
}
}
```

I know that this code is written in a very naive manner, but I want to know how I can improve my code, specifically about better design decisions and better error handling (should I have my own error classes?).

**Assumptions:**

- Any single `.gitignore` file can't be more than few hundred lines.
- `.gitignore` directory contains all the content and isn't deeply nested.

Comment: File system access in the constructor... ouch

Comment: @Dan pls let me know why it hurts?

Comment: I was originally writing a review, but I stopped half way through because I felt it was becoming more of a code rewrite. You can find the in-progress here https://gist.github.com/danpantry/fa7bb445481b6fe05bc2

Comment: @Dan interesting! I was thinking same that how painful it will be for me to edit code again and again here :)

Comment: For the proper context I am making the clone of [this](https://github.com/karan/joe) app in java.

Answer (score 4):

A few points that could be improved:

- `HELP_TXT`: is it really worth readability to slim down your code down by a few bytes? `HELP_TEXT` is better.

  - Same with `println`'s parameter: `String txt` \$\rightarrow\$ `String text`
- `Oye oye = new Oye()`: Sounds like a stereotypical Australian day, if this is the name of your script, perhaps consider a name change. `GIT_IGNORER` works wonders in the understanding department.
- `fileName.substring(0, fileName.indexOf(".gitignore"))`: there's a magical tool called `.replace`: `filename = filename.replace('.gitignore', '')`
- `line` is redundant and unused:

  > ```
  > try {
  >     scanner = new Scanner(new File(path));
  >     String line;
  >     while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  >         println(scanner.nextLine());
  >     }
  > ```

Answer (score 4):

### Printing or writing `.gitignore` files?

Your title says printing, your description says writing, and your code seem to indicate you are merely creating a `Map` of directory, which has a `.gitignore` file, to the actual *path* of the file itself.

### Class name

`Oye` is an unconventional choice for a Java class whose functionality is to display the contents of `.gitignore` files. Correct me if it actually means that in some foreign language. :)

### Directory traversal in Java 7

Pardon my knee-jerk ['are you on Java 8'](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101267/printing-gitignores/101301#comment185127_101267) comment-questions (at least until Java 9 comes out next year...), but you don't have to be on the latest version, at time of writing, to implement the right directory traversal code. It's already [made available in Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html), do look at [this quick write-up](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) and the relevant [`FileVisitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) interface. In my opinion, this should be one of the *few* classes in your simple Java application, you probably do not even require an instance of your `Oye` class.

### Simplification

```
private static void println(String txt) {
    System.out.println(txt);
}
```

This method is unfortunately wholly redundant... You should just simply use `System.out.println()` *for now*. Remember, [you aren't gonna need it](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it). ;)

```
private static void printFile(String path) {
    // ...
}
```

Hmms... this entire method can, and should be, replaced by [`Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) too...

Comment: In java 8, more idiomatic than a FileVisitor may be to use Files.find

Comment: Hi, I didn't use `Files` because I wanted to minimize the dependency on extra classes, wdyt?

Comment: @h.j.k, for the proper context I am making the clone of [this](https://github.com/karan/joe) app in java.

Comment: @h.j.k, I used `printFile` so that the user can see the content in the console or can redirect the o/p to a file for later use.

Comment: @CodeYogi `Files` is part of Java 7, so it's not like you need to put extra JAR files on your classpath when you run your Java application ***if*** this is what you are trying to avoid... I hope that answers your question. As for `printFile()`, you don't need to manually spin up a `Scanner` to read line-by-line, `Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)` gives you the entire content in a `List`, and then you're free to do whatever you want with the `List` instance.